# call printf using va_list

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

```
void TestPrint(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list argList;

    va_start(argList, format);
    printf(format, argList);
    va_end(argList);
}


int main()
{
    TestPrint("Test print %s %d\n", "string", 55);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to get:

```
Test print string 55
```

Actually, I get garbage output. What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use [`vprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/) instead.

Comment: @PingwinTux: Yup.  This kind of response was acceptable back in 2011 ;)

Answer (score 73):

Instead of `printf`, I recommend you try `vprintf` instead, which was created for this specific purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void errmsg( const char* format, ... )
{
    va_list arglist;

    printf( "Error: " );
    va_start( arglist, format );
    vprintf( format, arglist );
    va_end( arglist );
}

int main( void )
{
    errmsg( "%s %d %s", "Failed", 100, "times" );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

[Source](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/v/vprintf.html)

Answer (score 27):

As others have pointed out already: In this case you should use `vprintf` instead.

But if you really want to wrap `printf`, or want to wrap a function that does not have a `v...` version, you can do that in GCC using the non-standard `__builtin_apply` feature:

```
int myfunction(char *fmt, ...)
{
    void *arg = __builtin_apply_args();
    void *ret = __builtin_apply((void*)printf, arg, 100);
    __builtin_return(ret);
}
```

The last argument to `__builtin_apply` is the max. total size of the arguments in bytes. Make sure that you use a value here that is large enough.

Comment: thanks for that answer, which gives a straight solution to OP's problem. For interception purpose, this code saved my life! (or at least avoided me to defer to assembly :)

Comment: Can there EVER be a maximum for this value? The `__builtin_apply()` should parse the call stack frames in order to find out the value on its own. But it depends on the architecture if and how good this would work.
I once grafted a similar solution for myself. It was horrible.

Answer (score 4):

This is not how you use `printf()`. If you want to use `va_lists`, use `vprintf()` instead. Look [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/c/vprintf) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who needs more universal solution - try this template function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void myprintf(const char *format, Args... args)
{
    myObject.printf(format, args...);
}
```