# Good Verbosity Macro (C99)

Tags: c, macros, verbosity

I'm looking to write what I would imagine is a fairly common macro. I want to emulate the repeated "-v" options on many POSIX programs by defining a bunch of macros of the following form:

```
#define V1(str, ...) if(optv >= 1){printf("%s: "str,prog,__VA_ARGS__);}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // ... stuff ...
  int i = 1;
  V1("This contains a variable: %d\n",i);
}

// Output:
// ./program: This contains a variable: 1
```

where `optv` counts the number of "-v" options found on the command line and `prog` contains the program name (neither shown). This works well, but the problem is that I *have* to use a variable. `V1("Output")` will generate a compiler error. I could always use `V1("Output%s","")` but there should be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Or how about `V1("%s", "Output")`?

Comment: It doesn't seems you need a macro here. It can be done easier and simpler with function. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5977365/745924) for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GNU C preprocessor has a [special feature](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) that lets you delete the trailing comma when there are no arguments filling the variadic portion by prepending the token-pasting operator `##` to `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define V1(str, ...) if(optv < 1); else printf("%s: "str,prog, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

Alternatively, if you wish to remain fully C99 compliant, you could incorporate the the format string parameter into the ellipsis, but in this instance you'll also need to refactor your code since you want to include the extra `prog` parameter between the format string and the varargs.  Something like this might work:

```
#define V1(...) if(optv < 1); else myprintf(prog, __VA_ARGS__)
int myprintf(const char *prog, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    // Print out the program name, then forward the rest onto printf
    printf("%s: ", prog);

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int ret = vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return ret;
}
```

Then, `V1("Output")` expands to `myprintf(prog, "Output")` without using any non-C99 compiler extensions.

**EDIT**

Also note that I inverted the `if` condition in the macro, due to some weird issues that can arise if you invoke the macro inside an `if` statement without braces—see [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I was hoping to not need to implement a function, but based on the other answers it seems I have little choice.

Comment: On second thought, `printf("%s: ",prog);` gave me a good idea: `#define V1(...) if(optv>=1){printf("%s: ",prog);printf(__VA_ARGS__);}`

Comment: wrapping your function-like macro in a do while(0) loop could help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 2 different macros for each verbosity level; one which prints a message and variable, and one which just prints a message?

Comment: Because I already have 5 verbosity levels, and I also have == versions of the same. So that means duplicating 10 macros.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write yourself a small support function so that you can do the job cleanly:

```
extern void vb_print(const char *format, ...);

#define V1(...)  do { if (optv >= 1) vb_print(__VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
```

I assume that both `optv` and `prog` are global variables.  These would go into a header (you wouldn't write them out in the programs themselves, would you?).

The function can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

extern const char *prog;

void vb_print(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    printf("%s:", prog);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

There's no rocket science in there.  You can tweak the system to your heart's content, allowing a choice of where the information is written, flushing the output, ensuring there's a newline at the end, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define V1X(str, ...) if(optv >= 1) {printf("%s: "str,prog,__VA_ARGS__);} else
#define V1(...) V1X(__VA_ARGS__,0)
```

I believe that fixes the problem you described, and the `else` at the end fixed another problem.

Comment: Doesn't that generate a warning about too many arguments for the format string?

Comment: It might, if you have that warning enabled. In which case, you could use `"%s: "str"%.0d"` :-)

Comment: The whole point of this was to remove the too many args warning, otherwise I would just `V1("Output","")` and avoid the warning.

Comment: Also, I have 5 verbosity levels with == and >= versions so I'd like to not have to add 10 more macros in.

Comment: Make the operator or even the entire expression an argument to the macro `VXX` macro...