# Trouble Wrapping Printf in C Program

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to wrap printf in a C program (well, actually _snprintf but this example is simpler) and am having trouble getting the variable argument stuff to work. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void works(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", 100);
}

void wrap_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    printf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void broken(void)
{
    wrap_printf("%d\n", 100);
}

int main(void)
{
    works();
    broken();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
100
3668388
```

The args variable looks good after the call to `va_start` in my code, but as soon as I step into the C runtime code and they call `va_start` the value looks bad. Any thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [call printf using va_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
va_start(args, fmt);
vprintf(fmt, args);
va_end(args);
```

You need to call [`vprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/vprintf.html) instead of `printf`. The `v*printf` functions understand `va_List` arguments. I'm surprised you didn't get a warning.

Comment: when writing code here on stackoverflow, be sure to use proper code blocks, not quotes in your answer.

Comment: Thanks! No warning at all other than '_snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead.

Comment: @user1421964 You can define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to get rid of that.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing `args` which is a `va_list`, but `printf()` of course expects the arguments directly, it has no way of knowing that its second argument suddenly is a `va_list`.

You should be using `vprintf()`, the variable-argument version which does indeed expect a `va_list` and knows how to extract the values from it.