# Modifying printf

Tags: c

I would like to modify the function `printf` to a new function `printf2` that simply prepends the message to be printed with `Hello`.

I could do

```
void printf2(char message[]) {
    printf("Hello ");
    printf(message);
}
```

The problem is that I cannot pass the extra arguments for cases when `message` has `%d`, `%c`, etc.

How can I have `printf2` accept as many parameters `printf` can, and pass them on to `printf`?

Comment: Have a look at `vprintf`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/

Comment: possible duplicate of [call printf using va_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list)

Comment: @KeithHalligan: I'm on an embedded device, and I don't have `vprintf`.

Comment: Are you SURE you don't have vprintf()?  Perhaps you just didn't #include <stdarg.h> and assumed the resulting error meant you don't have vprintf()?  What sort of embedded device are you using, and what compiler?

Comment: @Randomblue - please provide some details regarding your embedded dev environment (compiler, C99, etc).

Comment: I'm developing for an STM32F2 ARM chip using the Yagarto toolchain (recompiled version of GCC). For licensing reasons, I cannot use the standard libraries. I have however found a `printf` function with a compatible license, but that is it.

Comment: Licensing issues fundamentally change the nature of your question.  I assume that the usual list isn't compatible with your project (GPL, BSD, etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment above points you in the right direction, but here is an example of how to prepend your tag (Hello).

Notes:
I have used the *s* and *n* version of *printf* to format a new string that shouldn't overflow my temp buffer, and *MAX_MSG_SIZE* is assumed to be defined appropriately elsewhere.

```
void printf2(const char *format, ...)
{

    char buffer[MAX_MSG_SIZE] = "";  


    va_list args;


    va_start(args,format);
    vsnprintf(buffer, MAX_MSG_SIZE, format, args);
    va_end(args);   

    printf("Hello: %s\n", buffer);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that a single call to `printf` is required; so the printing to string (with its associated MAX_MSG_SIZE limit) isn't necessary.  Move the `printf("Hello: ");` above va_start, and replace `vsnprintf()` with `printf(format, args);`

Comment: The print to string was necessary in the snippet my example was extracted from - but you are correct in that there are a couple of ways this can be accomplished.

Comment: Replacing `vsnprintf()` with `printf(format, args);` does not work. Replacing it with `vprintf(format, args);` does.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use below function to control the variable parameter.

   ```
   void va_start( va_list arg_ptr, prev_param );   
   type va_arg( va_list arg_ptr, type );   
   void va_end( va_list arg_ptr );
   ```
2. Judge the format string. using switch () statement judge `%d`, `%c`, `%s` and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_message(char *format, ...)
{
    printf("%s", "Hello: ")
    va_list ptr;
    va_start(ptr, format);
    vprintf(format, ptr);
    va_end(ptr);
}
```

Note:

1. printf("%s", "Hello: ") is bit faster than printf("Hello: ") (by
   skipping scan of the format string phase)
2. printf(message); is REALLY bad idea. It crash when message has something like "%s".