# Incorrect function call with variable parameters

Tags: c++, function, call

I am trying to make a nested function call with a variable number of parameters without retrieving them. And I get the wrong result.

Here is my simple c++ program:

```
extern "C" {
#include <stdio.h>
}
#include <cstdarg>

class ctty {
    public:
        ctty();
        int logger(int prior, const char* format, ...);
    private:
};

ctty::ctty(){};

int ctty::logger(int prior, const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,format);
    printf(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ctty tty;
    tty.logger(0, "Test %d %d %d\n", 7, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
Test -205200 7 5
```

I expect a result

```
Test 7 5 5
```

I don’t understand what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give more detailed information about what you are expecting and the difference to the outcome. It's hard to read code from others, where many types and functions are unclear

Comment: What makes you think that you can pass a `va_list` to `printf`? Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf.

Comment: `extern "C" { }` around a standard library include is clearly wrong. I doubt it is legal.

Comment: Duplicate of [call printf using va_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977326/call-printf-using-va-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly pass `va_list`  to `printf`. `va_list` is a wrapper around the actual list of arguments (whatever its representation is). Although C way to do should be to use `vprintf`, in C++ there are safer alternatives, like variadic templates allowing to create a safer version of formatted printing, e.g.  (a  fictional format string  for brevity of example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class ctty {
    public:
        ctty();

        template<typename T, typename... Args>
        int logger(int prior, const char* format, T value, Args... args);
    private:
        void logger(int prior, const char *s);
};

ctty::ctty(){};

void ctty::logger(int prior, const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%') {
            if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
                ++s;
            }
            else {
                throw std::runtime_error("invalid format string: missing arguments");
            }
        }
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
int ctty::logger(int prior, const char* format, T value, Args... args)
{
    while (*format) {
        if (*format == '%') {
                std::cout << value;
                logger(prior, format + 1, args...); 
                return 0;
            }
        std::cout << *format++;
    }
    throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to logger");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ctty tty;
    tty.logger(0, "Test % % %\n", 7.55f, "Tada!", 888);
    return 0;
}
```

This part of your code:

```
extern "C" {
#include <stdio.h>
}
```

Is technically an undefined behavior, while it may compile and not have adverse effect in some cases, it's not portable. You have to use C++ headers, e.g. `<cstdio>`